# Combine 2 different javascript json objects into one with a loop and joining on the questionid ,

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

So I am trying to combine 2 different javascript object than I can end up using in an angularjs ng-repeat .     since there is a 1 to many relationship from the database,  I was pulling queries separately.

What I have is this:

```
Main list of data  ,  3 object sample
0: Object
  $$hashKey: "object:4"
  Active:true
  QuestionId:2
  SalesChannel:"DTD"
1: Object
  $$hashKey: "object:5"
  Active:true
  QuestionId:3
  SalesChannel:"DTD"
2: Object
  $$hashKey: "object:6"
  Active:true
  QuestionId:5
  SalesChannel:"DTD"
```

Then another query returned data into what I want to relate as JSON into the other object

```
Object { Id: 3, Name: "Text box" QuestionId: 3}   
{ Id: 4, Name: "Text box" QuestionId: 3} 
{ Id: 9, Name: "Text box" QuestionId: 5}
```

So since I have both of these objects , I am wanting to combine.

Naturally I would think that I should return from the database, but then I also think about looping over and appending

```
for loop on main
{
....  find where main.QuestionId = sub.QuestionId   and it to be added in as a nested object of json type...
```

Thus the end result SHOULD look like

```
[{
  Active:true,
  QuestionId: 3
  SubData: [ { 
                Id: 3,
                Name: "TextBox
                QuestionId:3 
          },
          {
                Id: 4,
                Name: "TextBox
                QuestionId:3 
          }],
  SalesChannel: "DTD"
}]
 // and so on
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to go through all of the main objects, and assign to them only those results from second query. Use `Array.prototype.forEach` to go through them all, and `Array.prototype.filter` to select only appropriate results from secondary query.

```
firstQueryResult.forEach((firstObject)=>
  firstObject.subdata = secondQueryResult.filter((secondObject)=>
    secondObject.QuestionId === firstObject.QuestionId))
```

BTW, this has nothing to do with angularjs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach